# Automatic kanji conversion as you type for Japanese input?

Tags: language-support, ibus, input-language, japanese, mozc

I have Japanese input working on Ubuntu 20.04 via mozc, but one thing that I miss from my Macbook is the sleek convert-as-you-type feature. I currently have to press the spacebar after writing something in hiragana to trigger the kanji conversion, and while that's not a big deal, it "feels" a lot nicer to me to have the text converted as I type.

[image: japanese input]

I've never been able to find a similar feature for any of the Japanese input systems on Ubuntu, nor have I found any confirmation that this is explicitly not supported. Hopefully I haven't just blatantly missed something.

Is input like this possible on Ubuntu (whether via mozc or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know Mac's could do that...  But after you asked this question, I played around with my menu and I figured it out.

For me, I set up Ibus-Anthy.  I don't know if it works with any other combination.

Select Japanese (Anthy) in the menu and then:

1. Select "Preferences (Anthy)".
2. Go to the "General" tab.
3. Put a check mark in front of "Segment mode" under "Menu Visibility on Status Icon".

Then, under that menu option which now appears, you can select "Immediate conversion (single segment)" to get what you need.

If you go back to the "General" tab, you can select "Conversion mode" there but for some reason, I couldn't get it working just now.  My choice wasn't saving...I'd have to investigate that further.

Oh, and in my case, I'm using Ubuntu 20.10.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Yes, you can... however...

The thing you mention is ライブ変換 "Live conversion" from ATOK input system, the company in Tokushima, developed it around 2005 or so. It was introduced into Windows first and Macs next. You can actually buy this for Linux ATOK X3.

Ref: https://luxion.jp/2020/04/ubuntu-20-04%E3%81%A7atok-x3%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86/

1. I don't know they ask you to purchase this.
2. I personally found this is irritating very. Because, Japanese is a language without spaces in between the words, therefore the grammar often is taken badly and I must go back to correct them, so that work costs more than hitting a space bar each time.
   For example, 'youtypethissentencefirstandlatercomebacktoseperateeachwordoutofit.'
   Yay or Nay?

---

By the way, I found **suggest** function is more helpful than this automated one, that predicts like the bash tab key autocomplete. It remembers not only the most used words, the sentence can be used as a word, and it saves more than 20 keystrokes and normally a few. So the keyboard like HHKB layout which cursor keys are in the home position and/or combination with numeric keys and a PgDn key, you get a faster typing.

`sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`

Unfortunately, it is available only on fcitx-mozc, you can't turn it on with iBus-Mozc, the developer says some libraries are missing for ibus to do so.